# Remove comments from inner_html

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have some code that uses Nokogiri and I am trying to get the `inner_html` without getting the comments.

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@sql_scripts_url[1])) #using first value of the array
html.css('td[class="ms-formbody"]').each do |node|
  puts node.inner_html # prints comments
end
```

Comment: Please provide a sample HTML snippet, and the resulting string you would like after massaging it.

Comment: i just needed the HTML comments removed like "<!-- WHAT EVER-->" from my html. I used strip and it worked. I don't know if this is the right way though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you have not provided any sample HTML or desired output, here's a general solution:

You can select SGML comments in XPath by using the [`comment()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) node test; you can strip them out of the document by calling [`.remove`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-remove) on all comment nodes. Illustrated:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc  = Nokogiri.XML('<r><b>hello</b> <!-- foo --> world</r>')
p doc.inner_html                        #=> "<b>hello</b> <!-- foo --> world"
doc.xpath('//comment()').remove
p doc.inner_html                        #=> "<b>hello</b>  world"
```

Note that the above modifies the document destructively to remove the comments. If you wish to keep the original document unmodified, you could alternatively do this:

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def inner_html_reject(xpath='.//comment()')
    dup.tap{ |shadow| shadow.xpath(xpath).remove }.inner_html
  end
end

doc = Nokogiri.XML('<r><b>hello</b> <!-- foo --> world</r>')
p doc.inner_html_reject #=> "<r><b>hello</b>  world</r>"
p doc.inner_html        #=> "<r><b>hello</b> <!-- foo --> world</r>"
```

Finally, note that if you don't need the markup, just asking for the `text` itself does not include HTML comments:

```
p doc.text              #=> "hello  world"
```

Comment: I will try to use the first approach to actually parse .net config files and replace values with specific deployment environment values and deploy those files.

Comment: Even shorter is `doc.xpath('//comment()').remove` which removes all comments at once. No need to enumerate over them.

Comment: @akuhn Fantastic! I had not previously seen [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet#remove`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-remove). Thank you. I've updated my answer accordingly (and will have to go and update other answers around the site ;).

Comment: And if you have a fragment instead of a document... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787659/find-comment-or-text-nodes-in-a-document-fragment