# Find comment or text nodes in a document fragment

Tags: html, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have to clean up a Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment document (remove comment nodes and text nodes which contain whitespace only). Here's an example:

```
html = "<p>paragraph</p><!-- comment --><p>paragraph</p>   <p>paragraph</p>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse html
```

The document fragment looks as you'd expect:

```
#(DocumentFragment:0x3fc65f9f5870 {
  name = "#document-fragment",
  children = [
    #(Element:0x3fc65f9f5064 { name = "p", children = [ #(Text "paragraph")] }),
    #(Comment " comment "),
    #(Element:0x3fc65f9f4f60 { name = "p", children = [ #(Text "paragraph")] }),
    #(Text "   "),
    #(Element:0x3fc65f9f4e48 { name = "p", children = [ #(Text "paragraph")] })
  ]
})
```

How can I find all comment or all text nodes in this document fragment?

The following don't work because it's not a full document but a document fragment:

```
doc.search('//text()')
doc.search('//comment()')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
doc.search('.//text()')
doc.search('.//comment()')
```